# Unity - Visual Studio Community IDE1007 : The name '...' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development

This issue just appeared from nowhere. It was working just fine the day before. When I try to refer to any, literally ANY, data or var of whatever, the same problem appears, even when referring to a pre-declared var that was working fine. Whether it's a new or old used var the same issue persists. I've used both VS Code and VS community with no update or solution. Idk whether the Intellesence is working too. Any thoughts ???[image]
Note that in this example, this float is used below and works, but now when I try to use it again it just refuses to.

Comment: You cannot use that variable outside of any function

Answer (score 1):

In C#, you can't put statments (that are not variable declarations) in the class scope, so you can only access class members inside methods.

Comment: Ig that's it, just amazed of dumb this was. Thanks anyways